# SQL query for showing monthly report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with following columns

```
toolid, Quantity, dtfrom, dtto, projectid etc.
```

We have master tables for tools and project. The tools have license for a particular period say `dtfrom` is 1/1/2012 and `dtto` is 30/3/2012.

I have to show monthly report for quantity of tools purchased in a particular month.
The report will look like

```
sno  toolname projectname quantity jan feb mar apr ......
```

Please help in writing SQL query for it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do something like this:

```
select 
  sno,
  toolname,
  projectname, 
  year(dtfrom) as year,
  jan=sum(case when month(dtfrom) =1 and month(dtto)=1 then quantity else 0 end),
  feb=sum(case when month(dtfrom) =2 and month(dtto)=2 then quantity else 0 end)
       .....
from <table>
group by toolname,
  projectname,
  dtfrom
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of any performance issue you can try with PIVOT

```
select * from (
select sum(quantity) quantity,left(DATENAME(MM, dtfrom),3) month,projectid from test
group by DATENAME(month, dtfrom),projectid
) as p
PIVOT(
  MAX(quantity) for month in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
)as pvt
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f6c6/3)